# Call a div-container when my timer reaches zero

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to pop up a div-container as soon as the timer reaches zero. As well it should stop the timer, what i'm doing wrong?

Thats the timer in html:

```
 <div class="timer">Du hast noch <span id="time" style="color: red">01:00</span> Minuten Zeit!</div>
</div>
```

Thats the container i want to pop up:

```
    <div class="container-end-fail">
        <img class="closeup-collier" src="img/Flugzeug-bg.png">
        <p class="closeup-text">Du warst zu langsam! Er ist entkommen!</p>
        <p class="closeup-text">Wir geben dir noch einmal eine Chance. Wir zählen auf dich!</p>
        <a onclick="window.location='6-flughafen.html'">
            <button class="weiter-button" style="background-color:#5c7497">Nochmal versuchen!</button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

And JS:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }  else (timer = -1) {
        $('.container-end-fail').show();
        //you also may want to stop the timer once it reaches 0
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var threeMinutes = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(threeMinutes, display);
};
```

I already looked here for answers but many doesn't use this kind of timer I chose.

Thank you for your help!
Br Jasmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer reset everytime it was over (`timer = duration;`). Also, for the div to be displayed after the timer is over you need to hide it first with `style="display:none;"`.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (timer == 0) {
          $('.container-end-fail').show();
          //you also may want to stop the timer once it reaches 0
          clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
          timer--;
        }

      }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      var threeMinutes = 60 * 1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
      startTimer(threeMinutes, display);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">Du hast noch <span id="time" style="color: red">01:00</span> Minuten Zeit!</div>
  <div class="container-end-fail" style="display:none;">
    <img class="closeup-collier">
    <p class="closeup-text">Du warst zu langsam! Er ist entkommen!</p>
    <p class="closeup-text">Wir geben dir noch einmal eine Chance. Wir zählen auf dich!</p>
    <a onclick="window.location='6-flughafen.html'">
            <button class="weiter-button" style="background-color:#5c7497">Nochmal versuchen!</button>
        </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.. but the only thing is now that the button (weiter-button) won't show inside the div (container-end-fail). Do you know why??

Comment: Does it not work for you when you run the snippet or just when you use it on your project? What Browser do you use?

Comment: Found out the problem! i styled the button as well with display: none; - now it worked perfectly, thank you! :)

Comment: @Jasmin It will never stop the timer in background see my answer how I'm calling clearInterval

Answer (score 0):

It's simple convert passed time into seconds and decrease timer by 1 on every call of inteval, clearInterval when it's having timer value to less than 0

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(timer < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        timer--;
        if (timer <= 0) {
            $('.container-end-fail').show();
            clearInterval(timerInterval);
        } 
    }, 1000);
}
```